# Please help me spot my error

Tags: c

Hey I am writing a simple program that adds fractions. 
but whenever i run the program it will not perform the operations. 
It only scans the input, but no output.

please spot my error! >>>>>>CANNOT USE FLOATS<<<<<<<<

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main ( void )

{
        int lcd, d1, d2, num1, num2, sum;

       printf("Enter the first number:");
       printf("Enter the numerator:");
         scanf("%d", num1);
       printf("Enter the denominator:");
         scanf("%d", &d1);

       printf("Enter the second number:");
       printf("Enter the numerator:");
         scanf("%d", &num2);
       printf("Enter the denominator:");
         scanf("%d", &d2);


       for (lcd = d1; lcd % d2 != 0; lcd+= d1);


       num1 *= lcd / d1;
       num2 *= lcd / d2;

       sum = num1 + num2;

       printf("%d", sum); 



       return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You would probably find your problem if you used code that's clear and easy to read instead of being clever about it, especially around your `for()` loop.

Comment: Is there any constructive criticism? Not just a "don't do that."

Comment: Okay, I was being a bit oblique about it, but I was literally trying to say: "Rewrite your for loop so that it's easy to read and THEN debug."

Comment: you were trying to be oblique? Didn't you just tell me to be more clear in what I say/program?

Comment: No, not quite. One of the basics of programming style is that it's twice as difficult to debug as it is to create. So if it takes 100% of your brain power to write it, it's going to take someone twice as smart as you to debug it. Don't write clever code. Write clear code that you can easily understand the point of seventy years down the road.

Comment: One of the easiest ways to debug code is to print the key variables (`lcd` in particular, also `d1` and `d2`) in the loop.  That would probably tell you what's going wrong.  Also, don't forget to add newlines at the end of `printf()` statements. On many systems, the output won't appear until you print a newline or the program ends.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` must receive pointers

`scanf("%d", num1)` -> `scanf("%d", &num1)`

Because `scanf` use *call by reference*. What is that? please see the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int i)
{
    i = 1;
}
void bar(int *pi)
{
    *pi = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;

    foo(a);
    printf("%d", a); /* output is 2 */

    bar(&a);
    printf("%d", a); /* output is 1 */
}
```

In `foo(a)`, we're using *call by value*. That means `a` is **copied** when we call `foo`. the code, `i = 1`, of `foo` changes only the copy of `a`, and does NOT change real value of `a`.

In `bar(&a)`, we're using *call by reference*. Can you find the difference? Yes, it's `bar(&a)`, not `bar(a)`. "`&`" operator gets the pointer of `a`, and we call `bar` with the pointer. So `pi` refers to `a`, and `*pi = 1` changes real value of `a` successfully.

---

A real-life example is here: `printf` and `scanf`.

```
int i = 0;
printf("output number : %d\n", i);
scanf("%d", &i); /* input number */
```

`printf` doesn't need to change its arguments, so it use call-by-value.

But, `scanf` receives user's input and change its arguments into user's input. so it use call-by-reference. thus, we should use `&i`, not `i`.

Comment: -1: very difficult to comprehend what you're saying, especially for a newbie.

Comment: @ciphemagi: What should he say to explain it better?

Comment: It's not THAT hard. really? its just arithmetic.

Comment: Use less symbols that are reserved specifically for the C language, and more plain speech that demonstrates the point of the post.

Comment: ok , ok. I see you point.

Comment: Honestly, I think the people who are down-voting this answer are being a little harsh. If the questioner changes the line ikh points out, the code will produce an output. To understand why you need the & in front of num, would mean that you would need to understand pointers. There are a lot of places where the questioner can find out about pointers. And I don't understand why ikh must limit his use of "symbols that are reserved specifically for the C language" since the questioner is programming in C.

Comment: okay, okay. I've just written the reason..

Comment: @anon As you say, the reason is too difficult for newbie... I know most introductory books just say "the arguments of scanf must be after &." until it explain about pointers..

Comment: @anon It wasn't so much about the in-depth explanation as it was about the short, terse "->" instead of "because scanf requires the &operator." In either case, I reversed my vote because of the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be that complex? Why not just divide the numerator by the denominator?

Also, your working with integers. I think you want floats.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main ( void )

{
    int d1, d2, num1, num2;

   printf("Enter the first number:");
   printf("Enter the numerator:");
     scanf("%d", &num1);
   printf("Enter the denominator:");
     scanf("%d", &d1);

   printf("Enter the second number:");
   printf("Enter the numerator:");
     scanf("%d", &num2);
   printf("Enter the denominator:");
     scanf("%d", &d2);

   printf("%f", 
       ((float) num1 / (float) d1) + ((float) num2 / (float) d2)
   ); 

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: see? now that's constructive. I would vote up but I need more rep!

Comment: I inevitably knew I'd have to use a float but I know there is a way to do it without it. #giving myself a headache.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do it without floats. But what kind of result do you want? One with a floating pointer or some kind of fraction (1 1/2 for 1.5).

Comment: the goal is to add two fractions and the result will be the NON SIMPLIFIED sum. Apparently I an NOT NOT NOT allowed to use floats.

Comment: I think the goal of your exercise is to really practice. I can put you on the right way, but I firmly believe it's for the best that you work on a solution yourself. If I were to do it, the first thing I would do would be putting the fractions on the same denominator. After that it is easy. Sum the numerators and just have an int counter for your whole numbers and keep checking the division leftover, similar to the for you did in your code. If it is 0, this is the new numerator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the non simplified sum of two fractions, just using the following formula

```
a/b + c/d = (a*d + c*b)/(b*d)
```

Therefore, the following code could be used to achieve your goal

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main ( void )

{
    int den1, den2, num1, num2, sum_num, sum_den;

    printf("Enter the first number:\n");
    printf("\tEnter the numerator:");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("\tEnter the denominator:");
    scanf("%d", &den1);

    printf("Enter the second number:\n");
    printf("\tEnter the numerator:");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("\tEnter the denominator:");
    scanf("%d", &den2);

    sum_num = num1 * den2 + num2 * den1;
    sum_den = den1 * den2;

    printf("sum = %d/%d\n", sum_num, sum_den);

    return 0; 
}
```